# Display Firebase collection data to a container in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Can you help me with my problem? I can create data from a textfield in my flutter app and that data goes inside my firebase collection. What I  want to happen now is how can I read and display that Data inside Card with a Container child in my flutter app?

What I want is that data to be OVERLAYED or ON-TOP of the image

my code for that is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/Screens/discount_clicked.dart';

class DiscountCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  const DiscountCarousel({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 220.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int posiition) {
          return Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => DiscountClicked(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 190.0,
                      width: 300.0,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: Image.network("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2529787/pexels-photo-2529787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260", fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),),
              ),
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using realtime database or firestore?

Comment: Hi @PeterHaddad what Im using is ```firestore```. Also I managed to read the data from firebase but I have a new problem can you take a look at this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624082/created-data-from-firebase-database-keeps-overlapping-on-one-another